# loading a nib doesn't resize in universal storyboard; IOS, Universal Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, popup, autolayout, size-classes

I have a Master Detail application with Details section filled with table view, When a row in table view is selected it will load a nib (declared separately) that will act as a pop up (consisting of a PDF document). Until now it works fine, but there's this resizing issue, i have recently started using universal layout and have gone through lot of tutorials on starting with size classes and Autolayouts.

When i try to apply constraint on this nib, it doesn't allow me to do so, therefore resulting in smaller (in iPad) and larger(in iPhone) screens. by nib in above sentence i mean the main view(dimmed out view), while i can apply constraints on the middle, content view but that won't help.

Is there a workaround for this issue? did anyone face this type of problem before ? Any help would be appreciated. By the way, I'm writing my application in Swift, if this can be useful in any sort of way.

[image]

Comment: How do you add the view from the nib? You should add constraints to make the view fill it's superView, using visual constraints. If you could post the code where you add the view, I could give you a more specific solution.

Comment: This is my code to load the nib when a row in the table is selected. `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    
    self.popViewController = popUpViewController(nibName: "popUpViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.popViewController.title = "This is a popup view"
    self.popViewController.showInView(self.view, withImage: UIImage(named: "typpzDemo"), withMessage: "You just triggered a great popup window", animated: true)
    
  }`

Comment: I figured it out. If this can help anyone, just set the frame size of the nib to that of superView like this, "self.popViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame". Thanks @CatalinaT. for you point :)

Comment: That's great :).
But if you need to support different interface orientations, this solution might not work that well. You would need to add constraints or set the frame again in the orientation change callback

Comment: Hey @CatalinaT. , as of now i will just worry about iPad thing and it works fine. But i'm facing some problem in this, the size of the nib exceeds the present window size and the table is still scrollable. Im pretty sure there is some way to disable the scroll of the table view, but do you have any idea on why the size of the nib exceeds the present window. The "frame" thing that succeeded is pointing to the tableview's frame, is there a way to point this the View that is holding the TableView ?